# Set image of specific UIImageView using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview

I have an array of UIImageViews. I want to click on one of them and have the imagePickerController method set the correct image for the correct index of the UIImageView array.

```
var imageArray : [UIImageView]
...
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject:AnyObject]!){
    //What do I do here?
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
func pickImage(sender: AnyObject)
{
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion:nil)
    //what do I do here?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to `maintain` `tapped` `UIImageView` so when `UIImage` is picked from UIImagePickerController we can set it. Say its `curImgView`

Considering method is called when specific `UIImageView` is `tapped` :

```
func pickImage(sender: AnyObject)
{
    //setting currently tapped imageview here
    curImgView = sender;

    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```

Now when image is selected :

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject:AnyObject]!){

    //set image here
    curImgView.image = 'image here';
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```